# JWT generating custom token "array given"

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Following the docs I'm trying to generate custom Token using

```
$payload['user_id'] = $account->provider_user_id;
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
return Response::json(compact('token'));
```

It results in

> Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\Manager::encode() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Payload, array given

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of old but after struggling for quite a while i finally came to a solution for this. Most solutions i found on the internet say that the problem was in the jwt config file in the `exp` parameters (expiration date) for the token.

This did not solve the problem for the most users and that's because the problem is in the `sub` parameter.

Most solutions are like @Brenden's but you are going to get an error there that you are not passing the right claims. What will work is to use it like this:

```
$payload = JWTFactory::sub('token')->data($tempToken)->make();
```

`$tempToken` is your array of custom fields.

After you can simple:

```
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload)->get(); // mind the ->get()

return response()->json(compact('token'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will get you a bit closer?

```
$customClaims = array(
    'user_id' => $account->provider_user_id
);
$payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
```

Also, if you are using Laravel's backend, you can easily get the current logged in user ID in any controller using:

```
$user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
```